# Cannot list nor describe MSK topic's configuration with AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, command-line-interface, aws-msk

Is it possible to use the AWS CLI tool to list the Kafka MSK topics and describe the configuration of them?

The [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/iam-access-control.html) defines the topic's arn as this: `arn:aws:kafka:region:account-id:topic/cluster-name/cluster-uuid/topic-name`

I tried to execute the following command (some parts of the id is replaced wit X and the topic name with Y):

```
aws --profile dev --region eu-central-1 kafka describe-configuration --arn 'arn:aws:kafka:eu-central-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:topic/sre-dev-central-km-msk/0c4e35a9-XXXX-4d32-XXXX-76aa15890225-8/YYYYYYY
```

But I get the following error:

> An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the DescribeConfiguration operation: One or more of the parameters are not valid.

Comment: Just checking... is it because it is missing a closing quote?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `topic` ARN. But you [should be using](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/kafka/describe-configuration.html) ARN of  MSK configuration:

> The Amazon Resource Name (ARN) that uniquely identifies an **MSK configuration** and all of its revisions.

You can use [list-configurations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/kafka/list-configurations.html) to find ARN of configurations.

Comment: Ok, I got it wrong and mislead you with the describe-config command. Let me rephrase my original problem:
 - How is it possible with AWS CLI to list the topics of an MSK cluster?
 - How is it possible to get the configurations of an MSK topic?

Comment: @l4t3b0 Listing topics is a new issue, thus you should make new question. My answer correctly addresses the original issue that you reported.